# Filter data between two tables having one to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

`Client` table:

| [CID] | [Name] | [Age] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 12 |
| 2 | ACC | 15 |
| 3 | BBB | 12 |

`Status` table:

| [SID] | [CID] | [Status] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Active |
| 2 | 1 | Not Active |
| 3 | 1 | Unknown |
| 4 | 2 | Active |
| 5 | 3 | Active |
| 6 | 3 | Unknown |

The client table is connected to status table on [CID]. I want the [CID] of the clients who doesn't have any status set to "Not Active".

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT 
    A.[CID], B.[Status] 
FROM
    [Client table] AS A
INNER JOIN 
    [Status table] B ON A.[CID] = B.[CID]
WHERE 
    B.[Status] = 'Not Active'
```

In this case it should show client with CID 2 & 3 and not show client with CID 1. However, I'm getting all CID 1, 2 and 3 when in putting the condition that Status = Not Active. With the above query I'm getting all the three CID's.

How can I improve my query to show only CID 2 & 3 and what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` is the most efficient way to do this.

Unfortunately, SQL Server requires at least one colum in the subquery, so you can just do `SELECT 1` or `SELECT NULL`. Whatever you do gets ignored, it's just looking for the existence (or not) of a row in the subquery. Note the correlation to the outer query in the inner `WHERE`.

```sql
SELECT
  c.CID
FROM Client c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM Status s
    WHERE s.CID = c.CID   -- correlation
      AND s.Status = 'Not Active'
);
```

---

If you actually want to see all `Status` rows using a join then a window function might be the best option.

Here we use a window function which can calculate over multiple rows at once, while still returning all of them rather than aggregating. The `PARTITION BY` works like `GROUP BY` here, and the `CASE WHEN` makes it conditional so it only counts rows which match the condition.

```sql
SELECT
  c.CID
FROM Client c
JOIN (
    SELECT s.*,
      countNotActive = COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Status = 'Not Active' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY s.CID)
    FROM Status s
) s ON s.CID = c.CID
WHERE s.countNotActive = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain to me please what does SELECT 1 does in the 1st statement and how does the window function works please.

Comment: Thank you for clearly explaining the query. I understood the 1st query where the subquery returns all the ```CID```  which matches the status but then it compares it with the main query's ```CID``` to see which one's do not match. The 2nd windows function we are partitioning the records based on s.CID and also checking if the s.Status = 'Not Active' then give that a value 1  otherwise 0 and then only showing those records with countNotActive = 0.  I hope I'm right about 2nd query.

Comment: Almost: *give that a value 1 otherwise 0* no there is no `else` so you get `null` not `0`, and `count` doesn't count nulls. If you had `else 0` then it would count everything like `count(*)`. You can alternatively do `sum(case ... then 1 else 0 end)`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It worked and gave me correct results.

Comment: I have upvoted and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner join will returns ALL ROWS matching your criteria so you will get all CID with status that is at least once not active.
You should force the join and check for nulls.

```
SELECT A.[CID], 
       B.[Status] 
FROM [Client table] as A
JOIN [Status table] B ON A.[CID] = B.[CID]
LEFT JOIN [Status table] C ON C.[CID] = B.[CID] AND C.[Status] = 'Not Active' 
WHERE C.[CID] IS NULL
```

You could also do a GROUP BY or a COUNT(*)

```
SELECT A.[CID], 
       B.[Status] 
FROM [Client table] as A 
JOIN [Status table] B ON A.[CID] = B.[CID] 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM [Status table] C WHERE A.[CID] = C.[CID] 
                            AND C.[Status] = 'Not Active') = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would this return distinct records? Also, could you explain the second Select statement please, I’m new to SQL.

Comment: It depends if you add the word ˋdistinct` or not. The second query counts all rows with state not active for a specific CID. And the specific CID is kept if the count is 0 (no column).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understood the 1st query but I have a confusion about how the 2nd query works. In the 2nd query how would the main query filter based on the count value of subquery.

Comment: If your CID only have values that are not status not active, then you will get 0 as a count so (select ...)=0 will succed. If at least one CID has a status that is not active, count will be greater than 0 and cid will not be returned.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the [CID] of the clients who doesn't have any status set to "Not Active".

For me the clearest way to do this is to use `EXCEPT`, the SQL operator for (one-sided) set difference:

```
SELECT CID FROM Client
EXCEPT
SELECT CID FROM Status WHERE Status = 'Not Active'
```

This means "give me all the `CID`s that are in the first `SELECT` but *not* in the second `SELECT`"

Now, if you need *more* than just the IDs of the relevant Clients, you'd probably want the `NOT EXISTS` approach. But if you *just* want the IDs, this will do.